# Attribute Error : 'str' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy' with ChromeDriverManager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've just started with Selenium and I'm already stuck at the first step: setting up the driver.
I keep getting this error:

> 'str' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy'.

Here's the code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

And the whole traceback :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:49, in WebDriver.__init__(self, options, service, keep_alive)
     45 self.keep_alive = keep_alive
     47 self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, self.options)
---> 49 super().__init__(
     50     DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["browserName"],
     51     "goog",
     52     self.options,
     53     self.service,
     54     self.keep_alive,
     55 )

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:60, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, options, service, keep_alive)
     51 self.service.start()
     53 try:
     54     super().__init__(
     55         command_executor=ChromiumRemoteConnection(
     56             remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     57             browser_name=browser_name,
     58             vendor_prefix=vendor_prefix,
     59             keep_alive=keep_alive,
...
     63     )
     64 except Exception:
     65     self.quit()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy'
```

I'm using VS Code with Python 3.11, if that can somehow help.

Comment: Please show the whole traceback.

Comment: That's not a traceback.  That's just the last line.  Show the whole thilng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that the first argument is no longer `executable_path`, but `options`. (`ChromeDriverManager().install()` returns the path to the install location.) Since selenium manager is now included with `selenium` `4.10.0`, you should no longer use `ChromeDriverManager` at all.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# ...
driver.quit()
```

However, if you still want to pass in the `executable_path` to an existing driver, you must use the `service` arg now:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="PATH_TO_DRIVER")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Comment: getting error : ```#14 0x5621d9eec998 
#15 0x5621d9eecb27 
#16 0x5621d9f07c23 
#17 0x7f9748fb8ea5 start_thread```